# Dynamic If_else statement w/ Dates and Lags: If_else Not Working in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, survival-analysis

My data has a StartDate column, which includes the date the observation began a certain part of the study, ie patient A started treatment 1 on January 1st 2014 and began treatment 2 beginning June 1st 2014.

The rows leading (lagging) to the new treatment Date are blank. I would like to use an if_else statement to fill in the blank cells with the lagged Date. In the example below the 'StartDate' column is what I currently have and the 'NewDate' column is what I would like to end with. The cells "" are the blank, or NULL, cells that I would like filled with the lagged Date.

I chose to use the lag function because I was thinking that cell would chain off of each other ie cell three would copy cell 2, which would copy cell 1.

Any suggestions? Thanks

```
df<-data.frame(StartDate=c(as.Date('2014-01-01'),"","","","",as.Date('2014-06-01'),"","","","",""),
       NewDate=c(as.Date('2014-01-01'),as.Date('2014-01-01'),as.Date('2014-01-01'),as.Date('2014-01- 01'),as.Date('2014-01-01'),as.Date('2014-06-01'),as.Date('2014-06-01'),as.Date('2014-06- 01'),as.Date('2014-06-01'),as.Date('2014-06-01'),as.Date('2014-06-01')))
df$testDate<-if_else(is.na(df$Date),lag(df$Date),df$Date)
```

Comment: They wont chain off each other - it is executed in parallel.

Comment: Yes, as I was typing my question, I somewhat figured that was happening. Do you know of a way to make them so that they do chain off of each other? My next guess will be a loop then, any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're just looking for `tidyr::fill`, though it doesn't seem to work on dates, so you might need to convert to character as an intermediate step:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(chardate = as.character(StartDate)) %>% 
  fill(chardate) %>% 
  mutate(StartDate = as.Date(chardate)) %>% 
  select(-chardate)
#>     StartDate    NewDate
#> 1  2014-01-01 2014-01-01
#> 2  2014-01-01 2014-01-01
#> 3  2014-01-01 2014-01-01
#> 4  2014-01-01 2014-01-01
#> 5  2014-01-01 2014-01-01
#> 6  2014-06-01 2014-06-01
#> 7  2014-06-01 2014-06-01
#> 8  2014-06-01 2014-06-01
#> 9  2014-06-01 2014-06-01
#> 10 2014-06-01 2014-06-01
#> 11 2014-06-01 2014-06-01
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much; I'm embarrassed to say that I spent a LONG time trying to figure this problem out.

Comment: You could remove the `df$`